# 3rs Column falls on print preview

Tags: php, html, printing

I designed a new payslip format for the company I am currently in, I used PHP and HTML, it should be 3 columns per page when printed. It's fine when viewed on pageview but when I tried to print it, The Third column  indents down( -- -- _)<--just like this.

[image].

I hope someone can help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the page margins. For a single solution I would try to change these under `More settings > Margins`.

If you need a general solution, I would recommend the use of Flexbox.
You can find more informations about Flexbox [here](https://gapintelligence.com/blog/2017/the-flexbox-one-page-cheat-sheet).

Comment: HI, Thanks for the reply, I actually tried changing the margins already, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle as an example?